# Simple content change. Prev - Next Changes content

Tags: jquery, dynamic

Just out of curiosity i wanted to make something similar to what pretty much every image slider plugin does.. just without the automatic changing of content. ( With any content inside the set div. )

**Main functions would be:**

1. Hide Prev if content is First. Hide Next if content is Last.
2. Change the content to previous or next when one of them are clicked.
3. Show Prev if content is anything but first. Show Next if content is anything but last.

**Im having problems with hiding and showing Prev and Next.**
After "TEST3" content is visible and you press next it makes the content disappear, this is not desirable But if the hiding and showing of Prev and Next would work this wouldnt be a problem either.

Id like some help to get *this* code working *more* or less as it is. ( no matter how crappy the code is :D ) *Some tips regarding crappyness of the code goes would be great though..*

Edit: Right... heres the code :D http://jsfiddle.net/LKFt9/4/

JS:

```
$(".Content").hide();
$('.Content:first').addClass('Cont-active').show();
$('.Content:last').addClass('Cont-last');
$('.Content:first').addClass('Cont-first');

$('.Prev').click(function(){
    $('.Content:visible').prev().show().next().hide();
});
$('.Next').click(function(){
    $('.Content:visible').next().show().prev().hide();
});

    if( $('.Cont-first').is(':visible') ) {
        $('.Prev').hide();
    }
    else { $('.Prev').show(); }

    if( $('.Cont-last').is(':visible') ) {
        $('.Next').hide();
    }
    else { $('.Next').show(); }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="Prev">Previous</div>
     <div class="Content">TEST</div>
     <div class="Content">TEST2</div>
     <div class="Content">TEST3</div>
  <div class="Next">Next</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are assigning a class right at the beginning for `Cont-active`, although nothing seems to change or update that. However since nothing really seems to be using this, it's probably not important to fix.

It also seems that the hiding and revealing of your Prev/Next buttons is only done once, when the function first runs. You probably want these to run every time they are clicked. I would recommend wrapping these up in a function, and calling it on each click. Try this:

```
$(".Content").hide();
$('.Content:first').addClass('Cont-active').show();
$('.Content:last').addClass('Cont-last');
$('.Content:first').addClass('Cont-first');

refreshPaginators();  // needed so that the "Prev" button doesn't show when page first loads, since it isn't being hidden in any other way.

$('.Prev').click(function(){
    $('.Content:visible').prev().show().next().hide();
    refreshPaginators();
});
$('.Next').click(function(){
    $('.Content:visible').next().show().prev().hide();
    refreshPaginators();
});

// define a nice function for updating/refreshing the state of Prev/Next buttons which we will want to run anytime the content changes (and also when page first loads).
function refreshPaginators() {
    if( $('.Cont-first').is(':visible') ) {
        $('.Prev').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.Prev').show();
    }
    if( $('.Cont-last').is(':visible') ) {
        $('.Next').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.Next').show();
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Funka Oh thats interesting. I never knew there was something like this.. although i felt like there should be.. Thanks a lot. ( that .Cont-active was my lame attempt to mark the div that is visible so i could then hide .Cont-active and show it and so on.. but i realized that it was unnecessary. )

Comment: @Funka One thing though. You put refreshPaginators() once before the click functions.. im not sure why.. but wouldnt just moving function  refreshPaginators(){} and its contents over click functions have the same effect?

Comment: The initial refreshPaginators is needed to make sure the "prev" button gets initially hidden.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the refreshPaginators function is defined: it will only run when you call it. I have it so that it gets called once, right up front. Then, it gets called each time there is a click on either the Prev or the Next. If anything else were to change content, you'd want to call it from there too. I hope this helps!

Comment: @Funka well im still somewhat confused about that.. i mean 
refreshPaginators(); basically runs that code that is set in that "group" if you will.. so you say that the position of where it is defined doesnt matter, then i dont understand the "
refreshPaginators();" that is before the click functions because isnt the same thing defined below them? ( as in the original 
refreshPaginators code )

Comment: The position where the function is _defined_ does not matter. I happened to put the function definition (the stuff in the {curly braces}) at the bottom but could have just as easily put it at the top. However, the position where the function is _executed_ certainly does matter. So when we say `refreshPaginators();` that is our way of saying run the code in the function definition. It seems you agree that this is good we do this every time one of the Prev/Next buttons is clicked. However, if we didn't do it at first, when the page first loads, you would still have the "Prev" showing.

Comment: Just to clarify, creating the function isn't the same as running it. Your original code sample would just run the code immediately. By putting this into a function, it will now only run when we tell it to. (So we have to remember to tell it this!) I added some minor comments to my code in the answer. I hope this helps!

Comment: @Funka Ok, i think i get it now. Thanks again, this has been a big help.